# css drop down menu not working with IES6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

i have one CSS menu which works fine with all new browsers but not working with IES 6.
i tried alot but this did't work...
any fix for that.

Menu Code is

```
<div class="nav-container-outer"> 
            <ul id="nav-container" class="nav-container">
                <li><a class="item-primary" href="index.html">Home</a> </li>
                <li><a class="item-primary" href="#">About us</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a class="item-primary" href="vision.html">Vision </a> </li>
        <li><a class="item-primary" href="manage.html">Management</a> </li>         <li><a class="item-primary" href="faq.html">FAQ</a> </li>
    </ul>
     </div>
```

CSS Code is bellow

```
/*^'^ Navigation Structure ^'^*/
.nav-container-outer{
background: #990000;
padding: 0px;
height: 39px;
background: url(images/nav-bg.jpg);
}
.float-left{
float: left;
}
.float-right{
float: right;
}
.nav-container .divider{
display:block;
font-size:1px;
border-width:0px;
border-style:solid;
}
.nav-container .divider-vert{
float:left;
width:0px;
display: none;
}
.nav-container .item-secondary-title{
display:block;
cursor:default;
white-space:nowrap;
}
.clear{
font-size:1px;
height:0px;
width:0px;
clear:left;
line-height:0px;
display:block;
float:none;
}
.nav-container{
position:relative;
zoom:1;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.nav-container a, .nav-container li{
float:left;
display:block;
white-space:nowrap;
}
.nav-container div a, .nav-container ul a, .nav-container ul li{
float:none;
}
.nav-container ul{
left:-10000px;
position:absolute;
}
.nav-container, .nav-container ul{
list-style:none;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}
.nav-container li a{
float:none
}
.nav-container li{
position:relative;
}
.nav-container ul{
z-index:10;
}
.nav-container ul ul{
z-index:20;
}
.nav-container ul ul ul{
z-index:30;
}
.nav-container ul ul ul ul{
z-index:40;
}
.nav-container ul ul ul ul ul{
z-index:50;
}
li:hover>ul{
left:auto;
}
#nav-container ul {
top:100%;
}
#nav-container ul li:hover>ul{
top:0px;
left:100%;
}

/*^'^ Primary Items ^'^*/   
#nav-container a{   
padding:2px 34px 7px 15px;
margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
color: #003450;
font-family: Trebuchet MS, Arial, sans-serif, Helvetica;
font-size:14px;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight: bold;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: top;
}

#nav-container a:hover{
color: #fff;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
}

/*^'^ Secondary Items Container ^'^*/   
#nav-container div, #nav-container ul{  
padding:10px 4px 10px 4px;
margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
background:#7ACFF4;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
border-bottom: 1px solid #003450;
}

/*^'^ Secondary Items ^'^*/ 
#nav-container div a, #nav-container ul a{  
padding:3px 10px 3px 6px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
background: url(images/item-secondary-bg.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0px 22px;
font-size:11px;
border-width:0px;
border-style:none;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
width: 149px;
}

/*^'^ Secondary Items Hover State ^'^*/ 
#nav-container div a:hover, #nav-container ul a:hover{  
background-color: #FFFFFF;
background: url(images/item-secondary-bg.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
color:#ffffff;
}

/*^'^ Secondary Item Titles ^'^*/   
#nav-container .item-secondary-title{   
cursor:default;
padding:4px 0px 3px 7px;
color: #6C3600;
font-family: Arial, Trebuchet MS, Arial, sans-serif, Helvetica;
font-size:11px;
/* background: url(images/item-secondary-title-bg.jpg); */
background-repeat: no-repeat;
font-weight:bold;
}

/*^'^ Horizontal Dividers ^'^*/ 
#nav-container .divider-horiz{  
border-top-width:1px;
margin:5px 5px;
border-color: #C16100;
}

/*^'^ Vertical Dividers ^'^*/   
#nav-container .divider-vert{   
border-left-width:1px;
height:15px;
margin:4px 2px 0px 2px;
border-color:#AAAAAA;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean IE6 as in Internet Explorer 6? IES6 is something i don't know :-)

Comment: For our mutual convenience: http://jsfiddle.net/Qp7ks/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internet Explorer (5 and) 6 doesn't support/understand/respect the use of `:hover` on any elements other than `a` elements, sadly. So drop downs for IE6 compatibility almost always use `a` elements within the `li`s.

I am, unfortunately, unable to suggest working markup for IE6 compatible drop-down/fly-out menus, since I have no access to a computer running IE6; however an interesting page turned up over at [cssplay.co.uk](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/):

1. [Multi-level fly-out menu (CSS-only)](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/flyoutt.html).

References:

- [Compatibility tables at Quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t16).

Comment: The usual fix for this problem is this JavaScript: http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/csshover.html